# Is it technically feasible to dampen the control stick in an Autogyro?

Tags: experimental-aircraft, ultralight, amateur-experimental, autogyro

The control stick in a gyrocopter is too wobbly for a glider pilot's liking. Is there a way to dampen the stick in a Gyrocopter [Eg. the [Air command]](http://www.aircommand.com/aircommandsingle-503super-detail.php) to make it feel as smooth and light as one would in a Sailplane; without adding too much weight....

Comment: If we could get every aircraft to handle the same we'd be happy pilots... Unfortunately I think this is just something time-in-type will train out of you.

Comment: @RonBeyer I feel like it is technically feasible.Also, getting used to a wobbly stick would affect one's glider flying.